# Trying to use onchange to get the href value

Tags: javascript

I am not very familiar with javascript, what did I do wrong on the onchange in order to get the href value and put it into the input. Thanks.

```html
<a href="" onchange="document.getElementById('next_marker').value=this.href">link</a>
     
 <input type="text" name="next_marker" id="next_marker" value="" />
```

Comment: Links don't have an onchange event. Inputs do. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/change. You could use the onclick event, but then the issue is that your href is empty anyway.

Comment: links do not have a change event...What are you trying to do/detect?

Answer (score 0):

Link do not have `onchange` event, however it has `onclick` event. You probably can consider to user `onclick` instead.